# Lightning Component innerHTML fails without any error

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service, svg-icon

I've been using the SVG component from the related [Trailhead Module](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/project/slds-lightning-components-workshop/slds-lc-4), and it doesn't display the icon with LockerService activated.

I understand from this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/121115/how-can-we-use-custom-svg-icons-in-lightning-component-with-lockerservice-enable) that innerHTML is read only, thus the line `svg.innerHTML = '<use xlink:href="'+xlinkhref+'"></use>';` isn't executed as we expect and icon isn't displayed.

With the upcoming support of svg tag that's fine for me, but in a more global question, is it ok that this line fails without any error being displayed ?

Comment: I have same issue in our org. Is this issue fixed?

Comment: It is, I just tried again. You should create a new question on Stack Exchange and add some code sample to help us reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue and the fix is already making its way through the system - the issue is that the use tag is being filtered by the default behavior of the sanitizer library we use. We had to do some Locker Service work to be able to allow use.

Also good news is that in the next patch update to Summer'16 innerHTML, innerText, and textContent are fully support for both write and read :-)